# One Datasource for Multiple Schemas/Users

Tags: database, spring-boot, hibernate, microservices, datasource

I am working on a Spring Boot microservices project and I want to divide one microservice that has been done huge into 4 smaller ones. The main issue is that they are some tables (e.g. Customers table) that I want to be shared across all the new microservices in order to keep correlations-FKs. So, each microservice will have its own schema/user and all of them will have a shared one, as well, that will contain these basic tables (in order to avoid writing their Entities many times - one for each service -, I want to import them as a separate dependency through maven). First of all, I would like to ask you if that makes sense architecturally, and if yes, if there is a way to use one Datasource for two (or more) schemas/users - because currently I have managed to connect two Datasources, but I cannot correlate their Entities (the compiler does not permit that). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against this. If you want to keep referential integrity, and have dependencies between microservices you probably don't need a microservice architecture, but just some modularization in your code, which can help you cope with complexity as well. You don't necessarily need a HTTP boundary between code parts just to make stuff work at a better scale.

For the technical parts, I really think that using multiple datasources might result in a 2PC transaction, which you need to be very careful with.

"Correlating entities" could work by specifying the `schema`/`catalog` in the `@Table` annotation to refer to the respective namespace where the shared tables reside in.